# PHP executes bash script, redirect output to database

Tags: php, bash, shell, asynchronous, nonblocking

I have  queue of tasks that each can/will take a while. The task is ran using a bash script and a couple of parameters. When the user fires this task, he should be able to monitor the status (and thus the output) of this task. For this, the output should be stored in a database and the user interface fetches the current output.

How can I best run `fetch.sh` so each line of output is inserted into the database, and not only when the script finishes?

Would something like this work?

```
shell_exec("./script.sh | while read -r line ; do 
   sqlite "insert into history (str) values ("$1"); 
done &> /dev/null &")
```

Comment: how does fetch.sh get its parameters / instructions from your application? I guess fetch.sh is a cron job? So it has to query the database anyway, hasn't it?

Comment: As I call it from within my server-code in PHP, does it really matter? I retrieve the parameters in PHP and then pass them on.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would work for you:

```
$db = new SQLite3('mydb');

if( ($fp = popen("./script.sh", "r")) ) {
  while( !feof($fp) ){
      $line = fread($fp, 1024);
      $db->exec("insert into history (str) values ({$line})");
   }
  fclose($fp);
}
```

UPDATE

As it turns out - there is a relatively easy way to run this in a background

Say, our script is called logger.php

In that case - we could do:

```
nohup php -q logger.php > script.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Looks good! Any idea how I would do this non-blocking for the user?

Comment: PHP can hardly be a superstar when it comes to non-blocking scripts, microservices etc. You could probably give http://reactphp.org/ a try. That thing should allow you to create a background-running server that would do the job. I think you could also consider writing your service with nodejs instead.